# Remove Thunderbird from the indicator-messages

Tags: indicator, thunderbird, notification-area, indicator-message

Ubuntu 14.04. I accidentally started Thunderbird once, I do not use it.

Now I cannot remove Thunderbird from the indicator-messages menu.

As per the [doc](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MessagingMenu#API), I have tried to:

- copy the file `/usr/share/indicators/messages/applications/thunderbird` to `~/.config/indicators/messages/applications-blacklist/`
- rename `/usr/share/indicators/messages/applications/thunderbird` but not to remove it altogether

Any reason why this would not work?

Answer (score 11):

You can accomplish that using dconf-editor.  Just Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd>, type dconf-editor into the box, and press Enter to run it.

IF you don't have it installed, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

Browse to com > canonical > indicator > messages, and just delete 'thunderbird.desktop from between the brackets.  Logout, and log back in, and you're set.

[image]

Comment: This is working (as well as unchecking the option in Thunderbird preferences), but I would like to know why `applications-blacklist` does not work.

Comment: This did not work in 15.04

Comment: @rickfoosusa I just tried on 15.04, and it works.

Comment: which came first, windows registry or dconf?

Comment: I really don't know, but the Windows Registry was first introduced with Windows 3.1.

Answer (score 4):

I finally managed to remove Thunderbird by starting it and editing its Preferences > General settings to uncheck "Show in the messaging menu", and logout and in.

That does not explain why the `applications-blacklist` method did not work, though.

The [doc](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MessagingMenu#API) says also "An application should automatically register itself only if, and as long as, you have an account or analogous configuration set up in that application (for example, an e-mail account or a feed subscription)", and I never setup an account in Thunderbird.

Answer (score 1):

You can change by using **`gsettings`**:

> gsettings offers a simple commandline interface to GSettings. It lets you get, set or monitor an individual key for changes.

- **To get current setting, run following command:**

  ```
  gsettings get com.canonical.indicator.messages applications
  ```

  Example:

  ```
  $ gsettings get com.canonical.indicator.messages applications
  ['Gmailmailgooglecom.desktop', 'thunderbird.desktop']
  ```
- **To set new setting run following command:**  (Here removing **Thunderbird** from above example)

  ```
  gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.messages applications "['Gmailmailgooglecom.desktop']"
  ```

  How to Edit: All apps are listed by its desktop file with and `,` is used to separate them. you can **reorder** or **remove** or **add new** by this settings!
- you may need to **Logout** and Login back to show changes.

---

No any extra packages required to install.
Hope this helps to customize with command-line.